# Trigger Event When focus out in Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, events, angular5, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to trigger an event when textarea focus is out. I have tried to use (blur) also. 
When I use (focusout) the method was trigger. But  **[(ngModel)]** value saved as **[object FocusEvent]**

This is my component.html

```
div class="form-input">
<textarea class="form-textarea" rows="2"  [(ngModel)]="measurementPoint.Comment"   (focusout)="updateMeasurementPointComment($event, component.Id, measurementPoint.CompartMeasurementPointId)">
</textarea>
</div>
```

This is my component.ts

```
 updateMeasurementPointComment(comment: string, inspectionDetailId: number, compartMeasurementPointId: number) {
    this._service.updateMeasurementPointComment(inspectionDetailId, compartMeasurementPointId,comment ).subscribe(r => {
      if (r.m_Item1) {
        console.log(comment);
        this._notify.success('Saved', r.m_Item2);
      } else {
        this._notify.alert('Couldn\'t Save', r.m_Item2);
        console.log(r.m_Item2);
      }
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      this._notify.alert('Error', 'Unable to update the measurement comment. Please contact support for help. ');
    });
  }
```

This is Out Put---------

[image]

Comment: The output is because of you are passing `$event` into method, what you are supposed to get?

Comment: it is triggered and get the success alert. But data was not save.

Comment: Can you check in console what request and data is going into api?

Comment: I am sending ID , text value ,and another ID of component

Comment: Thanks Buddy. I fixed this issue. I just changed the $event it to [ngModel] value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUST NEED TO CHANGE THE METHOD HERE.... REPLACE THE $EVENT WITH [(ngModel)] value. Now it is perfectly work. 
Thank you everyone. :)

```
div class="form-input">
<textarea class="form-textarea" rows="2"  [(ngModel)]="measurementPoint.Comment"   (focusout)="updateMeasurementPointComment(measurementPoint.Comment, component.Id, measurementPoint.CompartMeasurementPointId)">
</textarea>
</div>
```